# Let $n$ be an integer, prove that $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor \geq (n-1)/2$

Tags: logic, ceiling-and-floor-functions

So far, I used the definition of floors to provide an interval. Then I did some algebra in order to get $(n-1)/2$. And I am able to deduce that $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor > (n-1)/2$, but now I'm stuck on proving them to be equivalent to each other.

$$(n/2) - 1 < \lfloor n/2 \rfloor \leq n/2$$
$$\lfloor n/2 \rfloor > (n-2)/2$$
$$\lfloor n/2 \rfloor -1/2 > (n-1)/2$$

Thus, $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor > (n-1)/2$.

But how do I prove that they could also be equivalent to each other?

Answer (score 2):

When $n$ is even, $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor = n/2$.

When $n$ is odd, $n/2 = (n-1)/2 +1/2$. 
Since $n-1$ is even, $(n-1)/2$ is an integer and $1/2$ is a fraction. Thus, $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor = (n-1)/2$.

Comment: Thank you very much.